# VB6 How to make functions work globally on all my forms?

Tags: function, vb6, global

I can't believe I can't find the way to make my functions work globally... Currently I have this same function at the top of all my 3 forms:

```
Public Function HTMLEncode(p_strText As String) As String
Dim strTemp As String
    strTemp = p_strText
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ó", "&oacute;")
    '... around 30-40 lines more like these ...
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "ÿ", "&yuml;")
  HTMLEncode = strTemp
End Function
```

But it is not only an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Programming_anti-patterns), it is really hard to maintain and it spamms my code a lot

I don't usually program in VB, so I apologize for the newbie question. But I have searched for hours and I can't afford losing any more hairs or hours because this.

Comment: As far as I remember, you can add a Basic Module and put global functions in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Project menu, select "Add Module", then move your function into that module, keep it as `Public`.  You should be able to comment out the other functions from the other forms since it can call this public function now.

Comment: do you think it can also work if I change `Private Sub Command1_Click()` to public and add it there? I have couple of buttons that do exactly the same on different forms

Comment: @ajax333221 The click event belongs to the local button, so just have each Command1_Click call the same public function or method.

Comment: You can call public funtions in other forms using Formx.PublicFunction(...)